# gossip protocol works on tcp or http

Tags: http, tcp, cassandra-2.0

The Gossip protocol used by many distributed systems e.g. Cassandra to communicate with other nodes in the ring. So, does it use HTTP or TCP protocol?

Also, what are the pros choosing one over another in distributed systems?

Comment: Don't use code formatting for text that isn't code. Off topic.

Answer (score 0):

You can use any protocol you want (tcp, http, dns etc) to broadcast information regarding the state of your nodes from a cluster. In my opinion , you should focus on a gossip algorithm, and not really think about the "protocol" word from the naming. At it's core, it's all about broadcasting information between nodes. Each node sending it's own view of the cluster state to a subgroup of nodes, and the broadcast keeps going until all nodes share the same view. There are multiple ways of implmenting such a broadcasting algorithm so research more about it or try your own model :) .

Here is some nice info and pseudo code about [gossip model/algorithms](http://www.inf.u-szeged.hu/~jelasity/ddm/gossip.pdf)

Answer (score -1):

HTTP and TCP are fundamentally different things as they work on different layers of the network stack:

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OSI_model

If you look at the OSI Model TCP works on the transport layer (Layer 4) and HTTP works on the application layer (layer 7),  The two perform different jobs.  The transport layer is responsible for providing the functional mechanisms for transferring data.  The application layer is built on top of the transport (and other) layers and provides items such as partner negotiation, availability and communication synching.

The two are not interchangeable with one another.

Comment: This should be a comment not answer. IT does not really help in solving the problem.